# why is the menu ul not expaning to fit right-align sub-menu items?

Tags: html, css, right-to-left, submenu

I have a simple menu with submenus. For left-to-right reading the sub-menu looks like this:

[image: ![Left-aligned]

The CSS is like this:

```
.hltrmenu ul.level-1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 1rem 0 1rem 1rem;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #acaaaa;
}
.hltrmenu li {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    padding: 0 0 0.5rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}
.hltrmenu a {
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
    position: relative;
}
```

But when I switch the code around so the text is right-aligned, it does this:

[image: ![Right-aligned]

And the `ul` doesn't expand to fit the list items.

This is my revised code:

```
.hrtlmenu ul.level-1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #acaaaa;
    width: 100%;
}
.hrtlmenu li {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    padding: 0 0 0.5rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}
.hrtlmenu a {
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
    position: relative;
}
```

I had assumed, obviously wrongly, that simply reversing 'left' to 'right' and vice versa in the CSS would do the trick.

Comment: Please include the HTML for this. Otherwise any responses will just be guesses.

Comment: The appropriate thing to do when asked to put more code in your question is, perhaps surprisingly, not to *remove* what code you already have. Questions asking for debugging assistance require a [mcve], per the rules of the site.

Comment: If I hadn't found the answer I would have put the html code in the first post. But it no longer needs solving as I solved it myself. Shall I move my answer code into the question and then add a note to say that it doesn't need fixing any more?

Comment: A minimal reproducible example's worth of your original, not-working code needs to be in the question. The answer can contain as little as the necessary code to change in order to fix the problem (but ideally the answer will contain enough to also run an example in a snippet, in the case of HTML/CSS code).

Answer (score 0):

Oops. My assumption was wrong. It would appear whilst preparing the abbreviated html for this issue that it was a simple case of not switching all the lefts into rights (or similar).

Here is a snippet showing both versions:

```js
    for (const selector of [".btn-level-1"]) {
        const buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)];
        for (const button of buttons) {
          button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            buttons.filter(b => b !== button).forEach(b => {
              b.classList.remove('opened');
            });
            button.classList.toggle('opened');
            });
        }
    }
document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (!e.target.closest('.menucontent')) {
    let elems = document.querySelectorAll(".opened");
    [].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
        el.className = el.className.replace(/\bopened\b/, "");
    })
    }
});
```

```css
.outer {
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.mt80 {
  margin-top: 80px;
}

/* left-to-right 
   ============= */
.hltrmenu button + ul, 
.hltrmenu a[type=button] + ul {
  display: none;
}
.hltrmenu button.opened + ul,
.hltrmenu a[type=button].opened + ul {
  display: block;
}
.hltrmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
}
.hltrmenu ul.menucontent {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f7a1d6;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.hltrmenu .menucontent {
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.hltrmenu ul.level-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 1rem 0 1rem 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #acaaaa;
}
.hltrmenu ul.level-1 li {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.hltrmenu li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
.hltrmenu .menucontent>li {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.hltrmenu li.linked {
  margin-right: 2rem;
}
.hltrmenu li.divider>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}
.hltrmenu ul.menucontent>li a {
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  position: relative;
}
.hltrmenu [type="button"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}
.hltrmenu [type="button"]:not(:disabled) {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hltrmenu button.btn-level-1 {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #0d6efd;
  height: 1.5rem;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 0 0 .5rem;
  margin: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 40px;
  top: 6px;
}
.hltrmenu button.btn-level-1.linked {
  right: -2rem;
}
.hltrmenu button.btn-level-1:before,
.hltrmenu a.btn-level-1:before {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0 .5em;
  content: "";
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
.hltrmenu button.btn-level-1:before,
.hltrmenu a.btn-level-1:before {
  top: 50%;
}
.hltrmenu button.opened,
.hltrmenu a.opened {
  color: red;
}
.hltrmenu button.opened:before,
.hltrmenu a.opened:before {
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 10px solid;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
.hltrmenu li.deeper button:before{
  top: 40%;
  right: 0;
}
.hltrmenu li.deeper.top-level>button:before{
  top: 55%;
  right: 0;
}
/* right-to-left 
   ============= */
.hrtlmenu button + ul, 
.hrtlmenu a[type=button] + ul {
  display: none;
}
.hrtlmenu button.opened + ul,
.hrtlmenu a[type=button].opened + ul {
  display: block;
}
.hrtlmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
}
.hrtlmenu ul.menucontent {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f7a1d6;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.hrtlmenu .menucontent {
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.hrtlmenu ul.level-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #acaaaa;
}
.hrtlmenu ul.level-1 li {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  float: right;
}
.hrtlmenu li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
.hrtlmenu .menucontent>li {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.hrtlmenu li.divider>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 2rem;
}
.hrtlmenu ul.menucontent>li a {
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  position: relative;
}
.hrtlmenu [type="button"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}
.hrtlmenu [type="button"]:not(:disabled) {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hrtlmenu button.btn-level-1 {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #0d6efd;
  height: 1.5rem;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 0 0 .5rem;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  top: 6px;
}
.hrtlmenu button.btn-level-1.linked {
  left: -2rem;
}
.hrtlmenu button.btn-level-1:before,
.hrtlmenu a.btn-level-1:before {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0 .5em;
  content: "";
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
.hrtlmenu button.btn-level-1:before,
.hrtlmenu a.btn-level-1:before {
  top: 50%;
}
.hrtlmenu button.opened,
.hrtlmenu a.opened {
  color: red;
}
.hrtlmenu button.opened:before,
.hrtlmenu a.opened:before {
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 10px solid;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
.hrtlmenu li.deeper button:before{
  top: 40%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charSet="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="menu-rtl-demo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outer"> The sub-menus here should align right-to-left.
        <div class="hrtlmenu">
            <ul class="menucontent">
                <li class="item-103 deeper parent linked">
                    <a href="/" >ITEM ONE LINKED</a>
                    <button class="btn-level-1 linked" type="button" name="btn-103"></button>
                    <ul class="level-1 not-separator">
                        <li class="item-104">
                            <a href="/" >Level two item with long title</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="item-122 divider deeper parent">
                    <a class="btn-level-1" type="button">ITEM TWO</a>
                    <ul class="level-1 separator">
                        <li class="item-121">
                            <a href="/" >Another Level 2 item</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <p class="mt80">The sub-menus here should align left-to-right.</p>
        <div class="hltrmenu">
            <ul class="menucontent">
                <li class="item-103 deeper parent linked">
                    <a href="/" >ITEM ONE LINKED</a>
                    <button class="btn-level-1 linked" type="button" name="btn-103"></button>
                    <ul class="level-1 not-separator">
                        <li class="item-104">
                            <a href="/" >Level two item with long title</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="item-122 divider deeper parent">
                    <a class="btn-level-1" type="button">ITEM TWO</a>
                    <ul class="level-1 separator">
                        <li class="item-121">
                            <a href="/" >Another Level 2 item</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```